# assign different values if two different options are selected jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck at a place in Javascript/Jquery calculation.

Please take a look at the link: 
http://thectiweb.com/booknow_new/

When the different option in the first row and second is selected, I need to show different values based upon those selection. Here is what I came up with.

```
<div class="row-fluid service">
  <h3>step 1: Select Your Service*</h3>
  <input id="proc1" type="radio" name="proc" value="120"><label for="proc1"><img src="img/simply.png" width="160"><br></label>
  <input id="proc2" type="radio" name="proc" value="150"><label for="proc2"><img src="img/pristine.png"  width="160"><br></label>
  <input id="proc3" type="radio" name="proc" value=""><label for="proc3"><img src="img/custom.png"  width="160"><br></label>

  <div style="padding-bottom: 24px;" class="pop" id="pop">
    <div class="popover fade right in" style="top: 137.5px; left: 861.033px; display: block;"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content error">CustomFitTM service must be quoted individually. A representative will contact you for pricing upon form submission</div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class=" row-fluid beds">
  <h3>numbers of bedrooms</h3>
  <input id="beds1" type="radio" name="beds" value="10"><label for="beds1"><img src="img/1.png"><br><small>one bedroom</small></label>
  <input id="beds2" type="radio" name="beds" value="20"><label for="beds2"><img src="img/2.png"><br><small>two bedroom</small></label>
  <input id="beds3" type="radio" name="beds" value="30"><label for="beds3"><img src="img/3.png"><br><small>three bedroom</small></label>
  <input id="beds4" type="radio" name="beds" value="40"><label for="beds4"><img src="img/4.png"><br><small>four bedroom</small></label>
  <input id="beds5" type="radio" name="beds" value="50"><label for="beds5"><img src="img/5.png"><br><small>five bedroom</small></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your Javascript code here, not as a link. It's also helpful to create a jsfiddle for responders to play with.

Comment: <script >
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($("#proc1").click(function(){}) && $("#beds1").click(function(){})) {

 var time ="2hrs";

}
else if ($("#proc1").click(function(){}) && $("#beds2").click(function(){}))
{
  var time ="3hrs";
}
}
</script>


i came up with this, but stackoverfow wouldnt let me post it in the questions.. i must have messed up sometwhere

Comment: Put your code in the question, comments are not formatted and unreadable.